# Splitting an Array into n accessible parts within perl?

Tags: perl

My goal is to take an array of letters and cut it up into "n" parts. In this case no more than 10 letters each piece. But I want these arrays to be stored into an array reference which I can access on a counter.

For example, I have the following script to split an array of English alphabetical letters into 1 array of 10 letters. But since the English Alphabet has 26 letters, I need 2 more arrays to access in an array reference.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#split an array into parts. 
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @letters = ('A' .. 'Z');
say "These are my letters:";
for(@letters){print "$_  ";}

my @letters_selected = splice(@letters, 0, 10);
say "\nThese are my selected letters:";
for(@letters_selected){print "$_  ";}
```

The output is this: 
These are my letters:

A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O  P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y  Z

These are my selected letters:

A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J

This little script only gives me one piece of 10 letters of the alphabet. But I want all three pieces of 10 letters of the alphabet, so I would like to know how I can achieve this:

Goal: 
Have an array reference called letters_selected of letters which contains all letters A - Z. But ... I can access all three pieces of size less than or equal to 10 letters like this.

```
  foreach(@{$letters_selected[0]}){say "$_  ";}
```

returns: A B C D E F G H I J # These are the initial 10 elements of the alphabet.

```
foreach(@{$letters_selected[1]}){say "$_  ";}
```

returns: K L M N O P Q R S T # The next 10 after that.

```
foreach(@{$letters_selected[2]}){say "$_  ";}
```

returns: U V W X Y Z # The next no more than 10 after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [splice](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) is *destructive to its target* you can keep applying it

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my @letters = 'A'..'Z';

my @letter_groups;

push @letter_groups, [ splice @letters, 0, 10 ]  while @letters;

say "@$_" for @letter_groups;
```

After this `@letters` is empty.  So make a copy of it and work with that if you will need it.

---

Every time through, `splice` removes and returns elements from `@letters` and `[ ]` makes an anonymous array of that list. This reference is `push`ed on `@letter_groups`.

Since `splice` takes as many elements as there are (if there aren't 10) once fewer than 10 remain `splice` removes and returns that, the `@letters` gets emptied, and `while` terminates.

Comment: Wow! That's really clever, and simple. Thanks so much! Would you like to comment on the logic of your code?

Comment: @xyz123  Yes, right.  The `splice` returns the first 10 chars, and `@letters` ends up shorter by that. The `[ ... ]` forms an anonymous array of that list, and that scalar is `push`-ed.  This is in a `while` loop over `@letters` ... which will terminate once the `@letters` ends up empty.  (The `splice` takes as many as there are, so we get that last batch for free :).  I will add this to the answer in just a little while...

Comment: @xyz123  It's like `while (@letters) { my @batch = splice $letters, 0, 10; push @letter_groups, \@batch };`  (here we can avoid the data copy `[@batch]` since `@batch` gets re-created every time).  Every time through `@letters` is shorter by 10 (the last time 6), and once it's empty the `while` is done.

Comment: OK, a downvote -- can someone give me any clue as to why ... ?  I'd like to improve this post as much as possible but I just don't see what it is.

Comment: This post had a "characters" instead of "elements" for what's in the array -- wrong in principle of course (mislead by the fact that it is chars in this example), fixed.

Comment: A character is an element as far as I am concerned.

Comment: @xyz123  Well, yes, thank you.  Which is why I ended up typing that (and in this case that wasn't strictly wrong).  But the text is about operation of `splice` in general so I should say "element."  However, I am really just puzzled with the downvote.  Thank you very much for the comment.  If I should/can improve that explanation please let me know.

Comment: @xyz123  The approach in the answer is quite like an example in the docs (linked), simplified a little and condensed to one statement.  It's common to have for the controling condition of `while` a simple data structure which is getting depleted inside the loop body.  And here `splice` gives us half of that :). You were right on -- you (rightly) went to `splice`.